# Query works in the console but not in the application

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with native query in hibernate 4.0.1. I have query that works in database console, but not in the application. I have:

Table named '**case**' have two columns that point to the same table - table named '**cost**', which have column '**value**'. My query look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), a.value, b.value, ...
FROM case AS c
LEFT JOIN cost AS a ON c.fist_cost_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN cost AS b ON c.second_cost_id = b.id
...
GROUP BY a.value, b.value, ...
```

Query is actually much more complicated but I do not think it matter, so I put dots. As I wrote this query work in the database console but in application error is thrown:

> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException:
>   Encountered a duplicated sql alias [value] during auto-discovery of a
>   native-sql query  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:594)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1986)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:331)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1585)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:224)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]     ... 138 more

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

**[Edit]**

There was mentioned that 'value' isn't proper name for column. That's true in fact this column isn't named 'value', but a bit different. My strict contract forbid release any kind of information about a code. I have to paraphrase it as much as possible, so I renamed all variables in fly and didn't thought that 'value' is wrong word. So column isn't named 'value', but the rest, still apply.

Comment: isn't `value` a SQL reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

value is reserved word, so you have problems. You need to rename your columns.

Comment: Or wrap the column name with ` symbol: `a.\`value\`, b.\`value\``

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think it will work, a.value in jpql query is name of property field (value) which is then mapped to db column 'value', so the a.`value` should not parse (but I have not tried that yet)

Comment: You can do this in the column mapping rather than in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an alias to avoid repeated ones:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), a.value AS value0, b.value AS value1, ...
```